# User types too many inputs, exception python

Tags: python, exception, input

just starting my journey with python. I would like to create a simple program that will take the input from the user and then do smth with it. But I am wondering what would happen if they put too many words. The error comes up and I cant get around with it.

```
name, surname = input("Full name: ").split()

try:
    print("Hello", name)
    print("Your login is:", surname + "ing")
except ValueError:
    print("Please type your Full name only!") #user type 3 words instead of 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the assignment inside the `try`, since that's where the execption is raised.

```
try:
    name, surname = input("Full name: ").split()
    print("Hello", name)
    print("Your login is:", surname + "ing")
except ValueError:
    print("Please type your Full name only!") #user type 3 words instead of 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you not use an exception in this way.  I would check your input explicitly.  Here's a way to do that:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Full name: ").split()
    if len(user_input) == 2:
        break
    print("Please type your Full name only!") #user type 3 words instead of 2

name, surname = user_input
print("Hello", name)
print("Your login is:", surname + "ing")
```

Result:

```
Full name: Joe
Please type your Full name only!
Full name: Joe Blow a b c
Please type your Full name only!
Full name: Joe Blow
Hello Joe
Your login is: Blowing

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for each value on its own like:

```
name = input("blabla")
surname = input("blabla")
```

or you could add it inside of the try/except which should also handle this error.

```
try:
    name, surname = input("Full name: ").split()
    print("Hello", name)
    print("Your login is:", surname + "ing")
except ValueError:
    print("Please type your Full name only!") #user type 3 words instead of 2
```